# HTML data and a string that looks like a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For this html

```
<div data-a="0123"></div>
```

this js:

```
console.log($('div').data('a'));
```

returns `123`. Is there any way without adding extra-chars and cutting it to get a string `0123`?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PXw2J/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bypass `data()` and grab the attribute directly:

```
console.log($('div').attr('data-a'));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/d5rXM/)**

Answer (score 8):

From the [jQuery doco on `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

So you need to say:

```
console.log($('div').attr('data-a'));
```

(Note that you specify the full attribute name, including the 'data-' prefix.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use:

```
console.log($('div').attr('data-a'));
```