# jquery data attribute removes leading zeros

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

i have this html.

```
<img src="2.png" alt="Pending" data-number="00991" data-status="0">
```

i am using the following jQuery to fetch the value.

```
var number = $(this).find('img').data('number');
```

above jQuery code fetches values with non-leading zeros, for example the above code will only fetch `991` instead of `00991` , what is going wrong?

Comment: (Virtually) Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7912601/615754.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use 'attr':

```
var number = $(this).find('img').attr("data-number");
```

Answer (score 17):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the `attr()` method.

So jQuery thinks that code is a number and drops the leading zeros. Use `attr('data-number')` if jQuery is trying to be too smart for your data attributes.

Comment: @Ibrahim: You should probably accept Josh's, he got in ahead of me.