# How can I get a HTML data value as a string with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my source HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" data-value="01">Test</a></li>
```

I want to get the value of the data attribute so I am using the following:

```
var abc = $(this).data('value');
```

This works okay BUT not if there is a leading zero. For example the above
placed the value "1" into abc.

Is there a way that I can get it not to convert the "01" into "1" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML data and a string that looks like a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912601/html-data-and-a-string-that-looks-like-a-number)

Comment: I'm not aware of `data-value` being a correct attribute of an `<a>` element. Wouldn't it be better to use the `rel` attribute?

Comment: @JakeJ - See http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @j08691 Ah so it's HTML5 it seems by a quick scan. However if it was me developing the site I would stay away from most or all HTML5 features (unless there was a graceful fallback) as to include all old browsers. Thanks for the link, learn something new every day :) +1

Answer (score 53):

```
this.dataset.value;

// Or old school
this.getAttribute('data-value');
```

```js
const a = document.querySelector("a");
console.log('Using getAttribute, old school: ', a.getAttribute('data-value'));
console.log('Using dataset, conforms to data attributes: ', a.dataset.value);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="01">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to @MaksymMelnyk for the heads up on [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Thanks, Florian, I usually prefer to answer with straight JS, if possible. Though, if the OP is already using jQuery, `attr` may be a better option, since getAttribute can be buggy across browsers in some edge cases, like when the attribute is one that is used by DOM, such as `obj.disabled`.

Comment: Well, you can use `this.dataValue` then :) I don't know of any bug around this.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I had never heard of that. It doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/uV9dv/

Comment: @JuanMendes,  @FlorianMargaine

`this.dataset.value` will have that value.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the attr() operator of jQuery:

```
var abc = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 14):

From the [jQuery data() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), it appears that you have to use .attr() to prevent the automatic type conversion:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method. When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

So, not to duplicate other answers, but rather to reinforce, the way to access the attribute without doing type conversion is:

```
var abc = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(this).attr('data-value');
```

This will return the string value with the leading 0.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried?:

```
$(this).attr('data-value');
```

or

```
$(this).attr('data-value').toString();
```

Comment: `$.attr` doesn't need `toString`, it already returns a string, even if it didn't, calling `toString` would not bring back the original string if it had already been converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
<article id="electric-cars" data-columns="3"data-index-number="12314" data-parent="cars">

</article>


const article = document.querySelector('#electric-cars');
 
article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.index-number // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community

Comment: please feel free to ask any questions regarding to that answer..! hope this will work..!

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
this.data('value');
```

I think this is best way to get data attribute value.