# how to get value from data-summary attribute of span using java script

Tags: javascript, html

how to fetch value of data-summary attribute of span using java script

example

```
<span id="summary-text" data-summary="this value needed">summary of contents  </span>
```

example
this value needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a HTML data value as a string with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015505/how-can-i-get-a-html-data-value-as-a-string-with-jquery). Note that the top answer uses native JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dataset` object to retrieve attributes prefixed with 'data'.

```
var data = document.getElementById("summary-text").dataset.summary;
console.log(data); //this value needed
```

[MDN API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yaxoyofiwi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: That's the way with ES6 :-)

Comment: @DaveEveritt I don’t follow.

Comment: .dataset is supported in the relatively recent ES6 version of JavaScript. The older way is .getAttribute

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById('summary-text').getAttribute('data-summary')` should work.